# OSM layer in Google Maps for Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I wonder if it is possible to show OSM ( Open Street Maps ) tiles instead of Google tiles on the Google Maps for Flash API ?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance; what is OSM?

Comment: Hi Flextras - OSM is shortage from Open Street Maps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash-mobile

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/flash

Comment: I already tried MapQuest - it is very good maping solution.
Anyway there is already done large scale project written on Google Maps Flash API, and i need to translate it to MapQuest API which is time consuming. I just wondered if there could be applied the temporary solution with the layer on top of Google Maps API untill i complete the transition.

Comment: Aren't map layers more like for weather, clouds, shops stuff?

Comment: They could be the map tiles aswell - just as Openscales and Umaper ones, but Google currently doesnt support external layers directly, so i am interesting if this could be achieved by some other way ...